# How to avoid IllegalStateException when start FCM service in Oreo

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

My app is quasi messenger app. And backend relay on fcm notifications for incoming message and so on. 
Till now my implementation works correctly (see below). But on Oreo I get IllegalStateEception. it seems that it is related to [background limits on Oreo](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#back-all)

I tried a workaround by call `startForegroundService(intent)` for Oreo instead `startService(intent)` but I get below error:

RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()

In manifest I have:

```
        <service
        android:name=".fcm.FcmService"
        tools:ignore="ExportedService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".fcm.FcmInstanceIdService"
        tools:ignore="ExportedService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

And in MainApp which extends Application class below method is called in onCreate():

```
    protected void initFcm() {
       FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, FcmService.class);
       startService(intent); //<- here is IllegalStateException 
       String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

       FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("global");
    }
```

Comment: You are getting illegal State exception for all the scenarios or only when you disable the notification channel you are hitting this exception ? I don't think you need to start the FCM service explicitly.

Comment: aurilio is right. The service is started by FCM, you do not start it manually

Comment: But they mentioned you can remove any restriction from the Setting .

Comment: ok. It seems that I don't need call sartService() directly. FcmService is started without that. Thx.